# Powershell string matching and move item

Tags: regex, performance, powershell, pattern-matching

I am in need of help finding the most efficient way to sort files into folders. The folders are account numbers and I have a million or so files I need to be sorted into their matching sub-directories. One issue I have in sorting is that the sub-directories of the account numbers iterate up. So I have to make sure not to sort a file into a partial match. Also the files were originally named by humans so the naming conventions are not always good.

For Example I may have these directories:

- D:\Directory\123-123
- D:\Directory\123-12345

And there may be files like these: Example files:

- D:\Directory\123-1234 Stuff.pdf
- D:\Directory\123-123 Banana.jpg
- D:\Directory\123-123456 Things.pdf
- D:\Directory\123-12345Things.png

In this example I would want 123-123 Banana.jpg and 123-12345Things.png sorted into the above example directories. I am running into issues with false positives in partial matches in the file names. My work around for that was to sort the arrays from smallest to largest and match in that direction. Also I was skipping files without a space because I could not figure out a way to properly match the file with the directory without doing so. Below is the script I have so far. Any help on making this more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

```
$destination = "D:\Directory\"

$dirArray = @()
$dirArray += Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Directory | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } -Descending

$fireArray = @()
$fileArray += Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -File | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } -Descending

foreach ($dir in $dirArray)
{
    foreach ($file in $fileArray)
    {
        $tempString
        if ($file.Name -match " ")
        {
            $tempString = $file.BaseName.ToString()
            $pos = $tempString.IndexOf(" ")
            $tempString = $tempString.SubString(0, $pos)
        }
        else
        {
            $tempString = $file.BaseName.ToString()
        }
        if ($tempString -eq $dir.Name)
        {
            Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dir.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really you just need to make your regex more explicit. Do you have any example(s) of the "false-positive"?

Comment: Jacob -
From the example I listed the directory D:\Directory\123-123 if I was matching against the "123-123" it would technically match the first part of all the files in the example. Like I said the there were no file naming conventions so sometimes there is a space between the account number and the description and sometimes not. That is why I was using the space " " as a place to tell the script match everything before the space. That is also why I was sorting from smallest to largest so that 123-123 directory would match the 123-123 file name first as it loops through.

Comment: Perhaps look into using the regex '?' value, which matches a specific character, or no character. So the regex string '123?-123' matches both '123-123' and '123123', just for example. Also try making it more specific, and using or (this|that). So you could do (123-123|123123|123 123) to match those three versions.